# NSUserDefaults not saving mutable array of objects

Tags: ios, persistence, nsuserdefaults

I'm having trouble making a mutable array of objects persistent using `NSUserDefaults`. I've been trying different code for days and just can't get it right. I've read everything I can find on the subject, including all the postings in StackOverflow. I know I'm close, but I would really appreciate someone pointing out what I'm doing wrong. I know `arr` in the following code winds up with a count of zero, and that's where I hit a roadblock. I haven't gotten past that point. I'll bet someone will laugh and point our my silly error within 2 minutes of reading my post.

Here's the relevant code, including the log:

Contacts.h:

```
 @interface Contacts : NSObject  // <NSCoding>
{
    NSMutableArray *arr;    // 8/21/13
}
```

Contacts.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
      NSLog(@"In encodeWithCoder");
      NSLog(@"In encodeWithCoder. arr's count is: %i", [arr count]);
    {
       for (int i = 0; i <[arr count]; i++)
       {
            NSLog(@"In encodeWithCoder %@", [arr objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSLog(@"class %@", [arr class]);
       }
     [aCoder encodeObject:arr forKey:@"allContacts"];
    }
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"In initWithCoder");
    arr = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"allContacts"];
    return self;
}

// The following two methods might not even be needed. I copied them from some examples.

- (NSData *)dataOftype:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data oftype:(NSString *)typeName error: (NSError **)outError
{
    arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"allContacts is ->%@", [arr mutableCopy]);
    return YES;
}
```

ContactStore.h

```
@interface ContactsStore : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
    NSMutableArray *arr;            // 8/21/13
    NSMutableArray *allContacts;    
}
```

ContactStore.m

```
    - (void)fetchContactsIfNecessary
{
    NSLog(@"in ContactsStore.m - fetchContactsIfNecessary #1");
    if (!allContacts)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"allContacts"];
        allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver    unarchiveObjectWithData:data]];
        for (int i = 0; i <[allContacts count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"In FetchContactsIfNecessary- Gettingfrom NSUserDefaults %@", [allContacts objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSLog(@"In FetchContactsIfNecessary- Gettingfrom NSUserDefaults - class %@", [allContacts class]);
        }
    }

    // If we didn't find one in NSUserDefaults, then create a new one.
    if (!allContacts)
    {
        allContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"In FetchContactsIfNecessary-We just allocated allContacts");
    }
    NSLog(@"in ContactsStore.m - Leaving fetchContactsIfNecessary2");
}


- (BOOL)saveChanges
{
    for (int i = 0; i <[allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"In saveChanges %@", [allContacts objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSLog(@"In saveChanges class %@", [allContacts class]);
    }
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    arr = allContacts;   // 8/21/13
        NSLog(@"In saveChanges. arr's count is: %i", [arr count]);
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"allContacts"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
       NSLog(@"We just synchronized allContacts - I think");
    return 1;
}
```

Log

```
2013-08-22 14:13:50.764 ImOK[16979:907] In saveChanges Scott Stringer, (212) 888-1234
2013-08-22 14:13:50.772 ImOK[16979:907] In saveChanges class __NSArrayM
2013-08-22 14:13:50.775 ImOK[16979:907] In saveChanges Sheldon Silver, (212) 987-4321
2013-08-22 14:13:50.781 ImOK[16979:907] In saveChanges class __NSArrayM
2013-08-22 14:13:50.793 ImOK[16979:907] In saveChanges. arr's count is: 2
2013-08-22 14:13:50.795 ImOK[16979:907] In encodeWithCoder
2013-08-22 14:13:50.796 ImOK[16979:907] In encodeWithCoder. arr's count is: 0
2013-08-22 14:13:50.798 ImOK[16979:907] In encodeWithCoder
2013-08-22 14:13:50.799 ImOK[16979:907] In encodeWithCoder. arr's count is: 0
2013-08-22 14:13:50.805 ImOK[16979:907] We just synchronized allContacts - I think
```

The names and phone numbers display correctly after the app returns from the background, but I get just four nulls after relaunching the app. I expected that because `arr`'s count is zero in the method `encodeWithCoder`, but I can't figure out how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your are only encoding and decoding your object. You don't store it yet. To store it you need a function like this:

```
- (BOOL)storeBrandOnDevice
{
    NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:self forKey:@"Contacts"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    BOOL dataSaveSuccess = [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    return dataSaveSuccess;
}
```

to get them from the store something like this:
- (void) getBrandFromStorage
{

```
NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    Contacts* storedContacts = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Contacts"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
}
```

}

and here is your missing function:

```
- (NSString*)itemArchivePath
{

    @try {

        NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

        return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"items.archive"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

It may not be perfect, but that's the general concept.

For more information about NSCoding, follow Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data)

Comment: Thanks Zoltan: unless I'm missing something, I don't see where you are saving to NSUserDefaults in your code example. I have two apps that save to the sandbox, but found that the data mysteriously disappears about every two months or so. I've been checking my data before I go to bed each night, and then again the first thing in the morning. The "persistent" data mysteriously disappears about once every two months.  I want to change my code to use only NSUserDefaults - and I must have a mental block about understanding how to save a mutable array to NSUserDefaults.